# How to edit OOXML in Office Add-in with Javascript API

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I have a JavaScript based Word add-in, which opens a taskpane. The document gets saved along with an opened taskpane, which gets opened the next time this document is opened (on Office 2013 and early 2016 versions). This happens even if someone else opens the document on a different computer.

I would like to remove this behavior. I found that it may only be possible by manipulating the OOXML of the document. I would have to set the visibility of the taskpane to 0 in taskpanes.xml part of it.

Is it possible via the JavaScript API?